# Xcode 8 says "Do you want to add a stub?" How do I answer?

Tags: xcode8

In Xcode 8, if you declare that a class (or struct) conforms to a protocol, but haven't implemented the required methods (functions?) Xcode will give this message "Type '`ClassName`' does not conform to protocol '`ProtocolName`'" which is true.

If you open the error by clicking the disclosure triangle, you will see a number of items with grey exclamation mark icons. Each item says "Protocol requires function ... do you want to add a stub?" I do want to add a stub! How do I tell it to add a stub for me?

Comment: This seems to be a lot better in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer of raphh is right but xcode is still a little buggy here (at least for me),

If you don't select the `Fix-it` right after compiling the dot mark transform to exclamation mark and you can't make it appear again unless you try to build one more time.

Right after building : 
[Dot error icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gWd9.png)

When you don't do the `Fix-it` right away : 
[exclamation mark error icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo0wf.png)

You have to re-build to get the dot icon again when you have several methods to implement and you did do the `Fix-it` for the first one.

Comment: I had same problem, but I can't find "fix it" button. I finally find button after REBUILD!

Answer (score 2):

Simply click on `Fix-it` and Xcode will add you the stub for that method you need to implement.

Like this. See :
[image]

Thank you Xcode 8, finally !

Comment: If you see a red exclamation mark instead of a Fix-it then look for more information on the error by clicking on the disclosure triangle in the Issues Navigator. If you see something about 'Candidate is not a function' then remove or comment out that code first and then the Fix-it will appear.

Comment: in my case it is showing again and again for adding protocol stuff which I already added 2 times...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, click 'fix it', xcode will add neccessary methods and variables as mentioned in your protocol, and one more thing, Xcode will add variables with proper read write permission in the class implementing the protocol.

For example:  in your protocol if you declare a get,set variable and in your struct/class you are declaring it as 'let' property, then Xcode will throw a error saying "Do you want to add a protocol stub", when you click fix it , it now add 'var' property in protocol abiding class/struct for a get,set property in protocol

```
protocol VoiceAssistant {
  var name: String {get}
  var voice: String {get set}
}

struct Siri: VoiceAssistant {

 var voice: String //xcode added this, when you click 'fix it' for protocol stub
 let name = "Siri"   

 let voice = "Voice" //added by me, Compilation Error: voice is not settable, but protocol requires it.
}
```

Comment: This question was originally about Xcode 8, but this is much better in the current Xcode (9).